# Гротескный/гротесковый - когда что?

Tags: паронимы

> И это объявленное автором любопытство толкало меня совать свой нос в
>   дела Печорина и даже влезать в его парные сцены с Верой. А
>   прославленная чувствительность княжны заставляла падать в обморок от
>   восторга всякий раз, как только Печорин обращал на неё внимание. Ну и
>   так далее. Так же гротесково *(гротескно?)* выглядели все персонажи
>   пьесы – за исключением самого Печорина.

(Это по пьесе Нины Садур «Зовите Печориным».)

Или это не паронимы, а выбирай что хошь?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Словарь считает эти слова скорее синонимами,** поэтому приходится выбирать самим:

Так же **гротескно выглядели** все персонажи пьесы – за исключением самого Печорина.

**Пояснение**

Мне кажется, что **изображают (особенно в театре) гротесково, а выглядят (в жизни, иногда в театре) гротескно.**

**Из Нацкорпуса**

**У "гротескно"** частотность употребления выше, но это потому, что слово относится не только к искусству, например: Старик в плавках делает **гротескно-значительные глаза**. [Татьяна Соломатина. (2009)]

**В теме театра "гротесково"** встречается чаще, и это понятно: мы же только изображаем чувства, характеры, но и **"гротескно"**  тоже используется (там их частотность примерно одинакова).

Для этого (хотя и не только для этого) ставили ее в Театре эстрады, для этого Лазарев решал спектакль **гротесково и раскованно**. [Т. В. Доронина. Дневник актрисы (1984)]

Отрицательные персонажи были выписаны излишне **гротескно**, как карикатуры в «Крокодиле». [Михаил Елизаров. Библиотекарь (2007)]

Comment: **Гротесковый** - претенциозное наименование, оно больше подходит для обозначения художественного стиля, которого _намеренно_ придерживаются, или для умозаключения о стиле со стороны. **Гротескный** же - обычное суждение о свойствах наблюдаемого. Это может объяснить и различие в частотности употребления.